# How to create an outlook attachment in-memory using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, attachment

I am using VBA to send an email with text attachment. Until now, I needed to physically create the file on the disk and afterwards reference its path.

Can this be done completely in mem?

```vb
    Dim outlook As Object, mail As Object, path As string

    Set outlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)

    ' write file contents
    path = Environ("temp") + "\file.txt"
    Open path For Output As #1
    Print #1, "This is my txt"
    Close #1

    ' attach file
    With mail
        .To = "me@awesome.com"
        .body = "This is a test"
        .attachments.Add CStr(path)
        .send
    End With

    Set mail = Nothing
    Set outlook = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Outlook object model doesn't provide any property or method for that. The `Add` method of the `Attachments` class accepts a file path only. More precisely, the source of the attachment can be a file (represented by the full file system path with a file name) or an Outlook item that constitutes the attachment.

However, you can use a low-level API - Extended MAPI on which Outlook is built. Or consider any third-party wrappers around this API such as [Redemption](https://www.dimastr.com/redemption). The `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` contains binary attachment data typically accessed through the Object Linking and Embedding (OLE) `IStream` interface. This property holds the attachment when the value of the `PR_ATTACH_METHOD` (`PidTagAttachMethod`) property is `ATTACH_BY_VALUE`, which is the usual attachment method and the only one required to be supported.